# Layer did not draw completely ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, hosted-feature-layer, drawing

I am trying to set the visualization properties of a layer in ArcGIS Online. After uploading the shapefile and publish it as a hosted layer, I go to the visualization setup window but a warning sign in the bottom left corner of the map is shown.

The pop-up in the warning symbol says 'the layer did not draw completely'. The problem is that even when I zoom in, the layer does not draw correctly, not even adjusting the visibility range.

The layer is composed of buffer polygons scattered all over a country and looks like this on desktop:

[image: Buffers]

I Have tried the following:

- Uploading the shapefile to ArcGIS Online with buffers as individual features (4200).
- Uploading the shapefile to ArcGIS Online with the buffer as 2 single features (using the dissolve option in the buffer tool).
- Optimizing Layer Drawing

Another detail to mention is that when I created the buffer inside ArcGIS Online the layer draws fine. The problem is that the analysis consumes a lot of credits and my account has reached the credit limit.

Any suggestions to solve this?

I am using ArcMap10.6.1 to create the buffers before uploading them to ArcGIS Online

Comment: I think you answered your own question. "The problem is that the analysis consumes a lot of credits and my account has reached the credit limit." you will need more credits to process (buffer) on arcgis online.

Comment: But why the layer created on desktop is not drawing properly?

Comment: Could it be some malformed geometry, massively multipart? Make sure you have run your buffer data through check geometry and repair if need be and steer clear of large multipart geometries. I would test by loading just a few and see if its not corruption caused by the upload step?

Comment: I checked geometries and no errors were reported. I took a subset of the features, uploaded them to AGOL, and they display fine. It looks like this is a size-related problem...

Comment: Use gdb and share it as service from arcgis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this solution you do need access to ArcGIS Pro. You are currently sharing your shapefile as a hosted web feature layer. In general this should work fine, but considering you are sharing a large amount of complex geometries, it might be better to share your result as a web vector tile layer. For a more detailed on how to set it up, see: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/overview/vector-tile-layer.htm

With a vector tile layer, you are still able to configure pop-up items for individual features if you desire, but the tiling  format is similar to tile layers and more efficient. It depends of course on what you want to do with the buffers, but if it is for more static display it can provide a workaround.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this alternative. I am working on ArcMap 10.6.1, I would like to see a solution that can be applied either on ArcGIS online or on ArcMap.

Comment: No problem, the integration between ArcGIS Pro and Online is definitely better. Nevertheless, ArcMap is also capable of sharing your feature layer as a tiled layer. However, then you might loose the pop up and editing functions. If that is not an issue it is worth a try.